# If you manifest Fission, kill yourself on the last round, and revive yourself with psionic revivify next round, is your Fission duplicate permanent?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, powers, psionics

"If you die, your duplicate remains in existence, and is for all intents you, but with two negative levels. (Once the duration expires, one of the negative levels immediately converts to one lost level; the other negative level can be removed by standard means.)"

So if I

1. Manifest [Fission](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/fission.htm)
2. Wait until the last round
3. Kill myself
4. Next round, after the duration expires, have my Fission manifest [Psionic Revivify](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/psionicRevivify.htm) on my corpse

Is the end result me with no penalties (not even xp loss) with a permanent duration Fission duplicate?

Answer (score 15):

### The duplicate is permanent, and it's you now; the corpse has no psyche to reunite any more

[Fission](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/fission.htm) says:

> If you die, your duplicate remains in existence, and **is for all intents you**, but with two negative levels.

It is **you**. Your former corpse is not you any more, it is just a corpse.

[Psionic Revivify](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/psionicRevivify.htm) says:

> Psionic revivify lets a manifester reconnect a corpse’s psyche with its body, restoring life to a recently deceased creature.

That corpse does not have a psyche anymore that could depart. Your psyche is your's, and you are the former manifest duplicate now, **for all intents**, including the intent to revive yourself.

Comment: Way more concise than my answer, while still getting to the core problem. +1!

Comment: So I assume that corpse would be just like an inactivated clone that can be used for the spell *Clone* but cannot be used for revival?

Comment: @TerryWindwalker It's complicated enough as is, I've not considered how or if clone is like it or not. My take would be that each of the two has their own rules, and should be judged on those rules.

Comment: This is incorrect. You intentionally left out the most important text. "Before the psyche of the deceased has completely left the body, this power halts its journey while repairing somewhat the damage to the body. " Psionic Revivify prevents the Psyche from completely leaving the body. So you are incorrect when you said there is no psyche anymore that could depart. Also, "for all intents" means "essentially". https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/usage-for-all-intensive-purposes-intents. So your duplicate is not you. It's essentially you but still not you.

Comment: Having said that, the trick doesn't work because the Fission dying does not prevent rejoining. Your dead corpse will rejoin your living duplicate when the duration lapses.

Comment: @fuzzywuzzy1951 Sounds like you thought deeply about these — best would be you make an answer out of your take. That way, it may not get lost like comments can, and people can vote on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As per your quote, Fission has the built-in side effect an auto-Raise, by keeping one of you alive even if the other dies. Since in this case it is your duplicate, they will be you with one lost level and one negative level.

## However...

The full quote paragraph of your quote is this:

> If your duplicate dies before the duration expires, **no rejoining occurs**, and you gain one negative level. If you die, your duplicate remains in existence, and is for all intents you, but with two negative levels. (Once the duration expires, one of the negative levels immediately converts to one lost level; the other negative level can be removed by standard means.)

Note my emphasis; if your duplicate dies, there is explicitly no rejoining. However, that phrase does not exist in the part you cited. This could easily be read to mean that your (dead) self rejoins with your (duplicate) self:

> When the duration expires or when you dismiss the power, you and your duplicate rejoin, no matter how far from each other you are. You gain back any power points the duplicate has not spent. At the time of rejoining, you take half of the damage your duplicate has taken since this power was manifested. This damage could potentially leave you with negative hit points, but it can’t reduce your hit points to less than -9.

So, your order of events becomes:

1. Manifest Fission
2. Wait until the last round
3. Kill yourself
4. (Dead) you rejoins (duplicate) you
5. Nobody exists to revivify, and you just gained a negative level

## Uno Reverse?

However, however...

> If your duplicate dies before the duration expires, **no rejoining occurs**, and you gain one negative level.

1. Manifest Fission
2. Wait until the last round
3. Kill your duplicate
4. Revivify your duplicate

At this point, your duplicate will have two negative levels, as per the Fission power, but **no lost levels**, since that parenthesis (arguably) only applies to a surviving Fission duplicate.

### Problems

The final paragraph of Fission reads:

> All powers affecting a fissioned creature, either the original or the duplicate, end when the fission ends. **All damage, including hit point damage, ability damage, ability drain, and ability burn damage, is added together**.

Note that this, unlike the paragraph on rejoining, does not seem to care whether any rejoining happens or either of you being dead, so killing your duplicate by any of the listed means will potentially leave you in a poor position to use Revivify.

### More problems

> **You can have only one fissioned duplicate in existence at one time; your duplicate cannot use this power.** You cannot use fusion or metaconcert with a duplicate, or share any other power or effect that pools abilities (the sum of you and you is still just you). Similarly, attempting to use powers such as claws of the vampire or vampiric blade to hurt your duplicate only damages your duplicate; these powers do not heal you. Empathic transfer and similar powers are likewise ineffective (transferring wounds to yourself isn’t a good healing strategy).

There are some limitations in place. Noticeably, you cannot repeat the process again until your duplicate dies. Which could, potentially, be solved with more Revivifys. The Fission power is out of play, generally, and your duplicate is not as potentially useful as another full Psion, due to the limitations.

## And then a DM came along...

So far, we've been reading the RAW thinking "how can we do this", not "how can we <strike>punish this</strike> make this interesting".

Psionic Revivify reads:

> Psionic revivify lets a manifester reconnect **a corpse’s psyche** with its body, restoring life to a recently deceased creature.

Your dead Fission duplicate's psyche is your psyche. If you reconnect your own psyche with your dead Fission duplicate's corpse, what happens to that psyche's connection to your own body?

1. Your psyche could connect to both, leaving you with two bodies (win!)
2. Your psyche could connect to the corpse and leave your original body, leaving you with two rather than one negative level and an original body without a psyche
3. Your psyche could refuse to leave your original body, making Revivify fail
4. 2 or 3, but some other existence uses the opportunity to connect to the psyche-less (soulless?) body, perhaps unknown to you

There may be other options, but I know which one I'd go with as DM. Hope your two negative levels don't get in the way of stopping your original body from getting up to weird things.

Comment: @alexstrasa82 Fluff is indeed irrelevant to theoretical optimization, just don't expect your DM to consider it irrelevant at an actual table. But RAW-wise, yes, the "reverse" should work. The issue with "killing the original" is the lack of "no rejoining occurs" text in the description of what happens, which means there is no corpse for your psyche to leave or be yanked back to.

Comment: If I understand the RAW portion of this answer correctly, attempting 'reverse' would leave both you and your dupe dead, with no one to cast revivify you'd simply be dead.

Comment: @RWolfe The idea in that portion is that you yourself never dies, only your duplicate does. So you, your original self, would be alive to cast Revivify on your dead duplicate. However, attempting to rejoin your own psyche to a corpse could very well prove fatal, but that is in DM territory, not RAW as far as I understand?

Comment: The line 'All damage, including hit point damage, ability damage, ability drain, and ability burn damage, is added together' to me sounds to me like, if your dupe dies, all damage it has taken is immediately transferred to you yourself, and unless I'm mistaken enough damage to kill your dupe should be enough to kill you.

Comment: @RWolfe That part I think I covered under "Problems". Note also the line, "This damage could potentially leave you with negative hit points, but it can’t reduce your hit points to less than -9.", so you won't die. I'd advise some kind of Death Effect, though. A Power Word Kill, for instance, would just kill your duplicate, without any actual damage happening.

Comment: The part of 'Power Word Kill' I'd thought of, but I'll admit, I haven't played 3.5e before, I haven't read the full spell description, I only went from the words in the answer, also I did not know that hit points could go as low as -9 before the pc outright dies.

Comment: Are you talking about reviving the duplicate in that same last round of the effect in your reverse or after?   As I read it,  if your duplicate dies, no rejoining occurs, and the corpse should then disappear when the duration ends of the effect that manifested it....

Comment: @Alan Source on the disappearing corpse? (I'm asking, as 3.x is a vast space, in which every detail matters, so I may be missing something)

Comment: @RWolfe In 3.x, you're basically up and fighting until you hit 0 hit points. At that point, you're "Disabled". If your hit points go negative, you continue "Dying" by losing one hit point per round until you reach -10. So if you rejoin after a Fission with -9 hit points, there's a one-round gap to stabilize you. Don't Google "3.5 drown healing". Injury and death rules: https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/injuryandDeath.htm

Comment: /@From Just reading the power Fission itself.  It has effect: Duplicate of yourself.  Duration: 1 round/level.   Unless something says otherwise, effects end when duration ends of a power.

Comment: @Alan Ah, my reading is based on how Fission itself states that it ends: "When the duration expires or when you dismiss the power, you and your duplicate rejoin, no matter how far from each other you are.", as well as "If your duplicate dies before the duration expires, no rejoining occurs". So the duplicate doesn't disappear after the duration expires, it rejoins you, unless already dead. Or if you are dead, it "becomes" you at the end of the duration. But this is unclear enough that a DM could rule as per your reading, outside of theoretical optimization.

Comment: Uno Reverse does not work. Power ends when the fission dies. Have you ever heard of summon monster not ending when the summoned dog dies? Same logic here. Fission death = power ends. With the power having ended, duplicate is unrevivable. Now there is an argument that says psionic revivify brings it back to life before it is 100% dead, but that's a whole can of worms and ambiguous grey area that ultimately ends in DM ruling so it's pointless to talk about that.